# Limitar casas decimais float c#

Tags: c#, float

Gostaria de mostrar o mediadesp e o mediareceit com 2 casas decimais após a virgula.

```
private void MediaReceitaseDespesas()
    {
        /* ----TOTAL / QTDE DE VALORES INFORMADOS----*/
        mediadesp = somadesp / despesas.Count;
        mediareceit = somareceit / receitas.Count;
        Console.WriteLine($"A média das despesas foi de: {mediadesp} R$");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"A média das receitas foi de: {mediareceit} R$");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: não dá pra saber muito pelo seu código... mas tenta `mediadesp.ToString("C2")` aí pode até remover esse 'R$'

Comment: Eu votei na melhor resposta que dá a solução real. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG2Nn.png https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Answer (score 4):

O método `Console.WriteLine(String, Object)` [*(ver doc)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx) tem suporte a *Format Strings* pelo que pode indicar o formato do output definindo uma.

Um dos [exemplos na documentação oficinal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#using-standard-numeric-format-strings) trunca o valor e coloca logo o símbolo da moeda:

```
decimal valor = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine(valor.ToString("C2"));
// Escreve $123.46 no ecrã.
```

Portanto poderá fazer algo do tipo:

```
Console.WriteLine($"A média das receitas foi de: {0:C2}",
```

Pode também especificar na *Format String* qual a [região da moeda](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier) e resolve o problema do símbolo `R$`.

Comment: Esta é a mais correta porque decide usar `decimal` que não tem problemas de exatidão.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a formatação {0.00}

```
Console.WriteLine($"A média das despesas foi de: {mediadesp:0.00} R$");
...
Console.WriteLine($"A média das receitas foi de: {mediareceit:0.00} R$");
```

Comment: Show mano, funcionou aqui. Vlw.